# My Unity game is showing suspicious behaviour and deletes file. Is that a place for concern?

Tags: malware, virus, gaming

Below is the behavior of my file in VirusTotal. Should I be concerned? Or is my Unity game good to go?

I used some scripts I found online. I'm using Photon so maybe the port 53 is normal, but what is the DLL being used there doing? Is it something problematic for a game to load? And why is the output log deleted? Is that normal in games also?

I can add a link to download the exe if anyone is interseted.

[image: VirusTotal output.]

Comment: What are the scripts that you found used for, and where did you find them?

Comment: Downloaded most of them from here https://github.com/xjimdim/Multiplayer-FPS-unity-project-
and downloaded another fps controller from a forum

Answer (score 1):

The few information provided don't look dangerous by themselves: there is an access to port 53 (probably DNS lookup), the removing of a single file which looks like a log file (output_log.txt) and the loading of a common library (commctl32.dll).

But of course a good attacker will try to not show any obvious malicious behavior in order to bypass detection. For example while port 53 is used usually for DNS it can be used for other communication to. And the file commctl32.dll might also load a different library then expected from the name. Also, smart attackers will detect that the code runs in some kind of sandbox or special test environment and not do any harm within this environment.

Thus, it is impossible to say if this is malicious or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
Do you know if theres a place I can send my file to check if there's a problem with it and for check ?

Comment: @McAs: this is a different question and thus should not be asked in a comment. Please create a new question where you clearly describe the problem you are trying to solve. Apart from that: use only third party code where you have a real reason to trust it.